# <pre> content rendering html unexpectedly

Tags: jquery, pre

When i am trying to show html code, the code is actually showing the resulting html added.
The html code within `cardcontent` is retrieved by a `$(this).click` event.

**Q. How can i show the code contained within "cardcontent" as expected within the `<pre>` section in the example below? (instead of it displaying rendered html)**
(Even though placed within `<pre>` tags the result is still rendered as html.)

[image]

```
function flashcard(cardcontent) {            
     flashcard="<div class='bg-slate-100'><pre>"+ cardcontent +"</pre></div>"
     return flashcard
}
 $(this).after(flashcard(this.outerHTML))
```

Comment: You need to convert the HTML you want to show to HTML entities. Wrapping the HTML in `<pre>` tags isn't enough. E.g. `&lt;div&gt;` instead of `<div>`

Comment: A `pre` tag does not mean it does not parse HTML, it mostly means it doesn't collapse whitespace.

Comment: @JuanMendes well dont i feel silly! i should have known that :')

Comment: Feeling silly is the best way to learn things, means you won't ever forget it 